# SQL query to identify all images within nodes?

Tags: mysql, drupal, drupal-7

Using Drupal 7, we have a need for an SQL statement which identifies all images in use, regardless of content type. The images will all be in the node body, and we're only interested in those that are published, not unpublished or superceded revisions.

Any ideas where to start on this? It has to be an SQL query (or a Drush command). We can't do it in a Drupal module, because we're outside a deploy window for the site i.e, if we wrote a module, it would be at least two weeks before we can deploy the module to the production servers where we need to run this. We *do* have SQL access on the prod server - we're the systems team, not the developers.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you mean by "all images"? All fields in "image" field type or something else? Consider using views module - would be much easier to achieve that.

Comment: @milanG - We're outside a deploy window, so I can't use the views module (The views UI is disabled on production servers). At the moment I'm looking for "img" tags within the node 'body' field.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean "node body" in the sense every drupaler know - "body" field(1), or it is just "everything that node stores"(2)?

1. Drupal default node Body field is a long text field and images can be placed there as regular `<img>` tags. If those images are what you need then you need to query `field_data_body` table.
   *Note that there's also possibility that images and other objects can be embedded using contrib modules such as `video_embed_field`. I'm not sure of how they store embedded data.*
2. In that case you need to figure out all image fields first. You may refer to `field_config` table for the list of all fields and their types. Then you can query every field (each field is a separate table) for values.

It's relatively easy task for simple sites, however you can find a lot of bumps on that road with more advanced setups.

Comment: Thanks! That's given me some paths to go on. Eventually we will need to find everything in a node, but just the actual body field will be a starting point.